# Spring / JPA / ReST Controller - returning a List of objects

Tags: java, spring, rest, jpa

I have a Spring Boot project where a Rest controller has a method that returns a DTO consisting of a List of entities.

```
@RestController
public class PersonnelController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/personnel/GetByFirstNameOrLastNameOrSSN/{paramValue}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ResponseEntity<GetPageablePersonnelOutput> FindByLastNameOrFirstNameOrSSN  (@PathVariable String paramValue) {

        GetPageablePersonnelByLastNameOrFirstNameOrSSNInput gu = new GetPageablePersonnelByLastNameOrFirstNameOrSSNInput();

        gu.setLastNameOrFirstNameOrSSN(paramValue);

        GetPageablePersonnelOutput go = personnelAppService.FindByLastNameOrFirstNameOrSSN(gu);

        if(go == null)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity(new EmptyJsonResponse(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        ResponseEntity rs =  new ResponseEntity(go, HttpStatus.OK);

        return rs;
    }
}
```

The code for the DTO is as follows:

```
package com.stsi.pss.application.Model.Dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Model.PersonnelDetailsEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Model.PersonnelEntity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class GetPageablePersonnelOutput {
    private List<PersonnelEntity> personnel;
    public List<PersonnelEntity> getPersonnel() {
        return personnel;
    }
    public void setPersonnel(List<PersonnelEntity> personnel) {
        this.personnel = personnel;
    }
}
```

The abbreviated code for the PersonnelEntity is as follows:

```
package com.stsi.pss.domain.Model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.BaseClasses.AuditedEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Model.LookupEntities.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Personnel", schema = "dbo", catalog = "PSSV2Db")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = PersonnelEntity.class)

public class PersonnelEntity extends AuditedEntity<String> {

    private Long id;
    private Long workforceId;
    private String workPhoneNumber;
    private String workEmailAddress;
    private String UPN;
    private String currentPosition;
    private Boolean isSponsored;
    private LocalDate dateOfSponsorship;
    private String sponsorPersonnelId;
    private Boolean isLEO;
    private Boolean isFERO;
    private Boolean requireComputerAndEmailAccess;
    private Boolean isPriorityCase;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PersonnelId", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

....other getters/setters/columns/relationships definitions here....

}
```

When I perform a search and the result has 2 PersonnelEntity objects, the first entity object is returning fine with the full object graph, but the second PersonnelEntity objects just returns it's id (id:2).  The response is something similar to the following:

```
{
    "personnel": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "creatorUserId": "sunil",
            "creationTime": "2018-06-03T03:09:02.963+0000",
            "lastModifierUserId": "sunil",
            "lastModificationTime": "2018-06-03T03:09:02.963+0000",
            "workforceId": 999323456,
            "workPhoneNumber": null,
            "workEmailAddress": null,
            "currentPosition": null,
            "isSponsored": null,
            "dateOfSponsorship": null,
            "sponsorPersonnelId": null,
            "isLEO": true,
            "isFERO": false,
            "requireComputerAndEmailAccess": true,
            "isPriorityCase": false,
            "building": {
                "id": 9,
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "creationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "isActive": true,
                "buildingName": "Federal Building, Post Office and Courthouse",
                "buildingNumber": "275",
                "displayGlobal": false,
                "facilityName": "Federal Building, Post Office and Courthouse",
                "facilityNumber": "15",
                "personnel": [
                    3
                ],
                "locationCityState": {
                    "id": 95,
                    "creatorUserId": null,
                    "creationTime": null,
                    "lastModifierUserId": null,
                    "lastModificationTime": null,
                    "cityName": "WINCHESTER",
                    "isActive": true,
                    "personnel": [
                        3
                    ],
                    "building": [
                        9
                    ],
                    "stateCode": {
                        "id": 52,
                        "creatorUserId": null,
                        "creationTime": null,
                        "lastModifierUserId": null,
                        "lastModificationTime": null,
                        "code": "TN",
                        "description": "TENNESSEE",
                        "isActive": true,
                        "locationCityState": [
                            95,
                            {
                                "id": 93,
                                "creatorUserId": null,
                                "creationTime": null,
                                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                "lastModificationTime": null,
                                "cityName": "NASHVILLE",
                                "isActive": true,
                                "personnel": [],
                                "building": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 80,
                                        "creatorUserId": null,
                                        "creationTime": null,
                                        "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                        "lastModificationTime": null,
                                        "isActive": true,
                                        "buildingName": "Nashville Resident Office",
                                        "buildingNumber": "342",
                                        "displayGlobal": false,
                                        "facilityName": "Nashville Resident Office",
                                        "facilityNumber": "19",
                                        "personnel": [],
                                        "locationCityState": 93
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 81,
                                        "creatorUserId": null,
                                        "creationTime": null,
                                        "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                        "lastModificationTime": null,
                                        "isActive": true,
                                        "buildingName": "Estes Kefauver Federal Building Parking",
                                        "buildingNumber": "281",
                                        "displayGlobal": false,
                                        "facilityName": "Estes Kefauver Federal Building Parking",
                                        "facilityNumber": "256",
                                        "personnel": [],
                                        "locationCityState": 93
                                    }
                                ],
                                "stateCode": 52
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 94,
                                "creatorUserId": null,
                                "creationTime": null,
                                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                "lastModificationTime": null,
                                "cityName": "KNOXVILLE",
                                "isActive": true,
                                "personnel": [],
                                "building": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 10,
                                        "creatorUserId": null,
                                        "creationTime": null,
                                        "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                        "lastModificationTime": null,
                                        "isActive": true,
                                        "buildingName": "Knoxville Resident Office",
                                        "buildingNumber": "283",
                                        "displayGlobal": false,
                                        "facilityName": "Knoxville Resident Office",
                                        "facilityNumber": "74",
                                        "personnel": [],
                                        "locationCityState": 94
                                    }
                                ],
                                "stateCode": 52
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 92,
                                "creatorUserId": null,
                                "creationTime": null,
                                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                "lastModificationTime": null,
                                "cityName": "JACKSON",
                                "isActive": true,
                                "personnel": [],
                                "building": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 98,
                                        "creatorUserId": null,
                                        "creationTime": null,
                                        "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                        "lastModificationTime": null,
                                        "isActive": true,
                                        "buildingName": "Ed Jones Federal Building & Courthouse",
                                        "buildingNumber": "341",
                                        "displayGlobal": false,
                                        "facilityName": "Ed Jones Federal Building & Courthouse",
                                        "facilityNumber": "128",
                                        "personnel": [],
                                        "locationCityState": 92
                                    }
                                ],
                                "stateCode": 52
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            "locationCityState": 95,
            "personnelStatus": {
                "id": 1,
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "creationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "status": "Active",
                "description": "Active",
                "isActive": true,
                "personnel": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "creatorUserId": null,
                        "creationTime": null,
                        "lastModifierUserId": null,
                        "lastModificationTime": null,
                        "workforceId": 9994323221,
                        "workPhoneNumber": "7034563452",
                        "workEmailAddress": "skosuri@epa.gov",
                        "currentPosition": "Developer",
                        "isSponsored": false,
                        "dateOfSponsorship": null,
                        "sponsorPersonnelId": null,
                        "isLEO": true,
                        "isFERO": false,
                        "requireComputerAndEmailAccess": true,
                        "isPriorityCase": false,
                        "building": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "creatorUserId": null,
                            "creationTime": null,
                            "lastModifierUserId": null,
                            "lastModificationTime": null,
                            "isActive": true,
                            "buildingName": "Robert C Byrd Courthouse and FOB",
                            "buildingNumber": "406",
                            "displayGlobal": false,
                            "facilityName": "Robert C Byrd Courthouse",
                            "facilityNumber": "107",
                            "personnel": [
                                2
                            ],
                            "locationCityState": {
                                "id": 109,
                                "creatorUserId": null,
                                "creationTime": null,
                                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                "lastModificationTime": null,
                                "cityName": "CHARLESTON",
                                "isActive": true,
                                "personnel": [
                                    2
                                ],
                                "building": [
                                    1
                                ],
                                "stateCode": {
                                    "id": 58,
                                    "creatorUserId": null,
                                    "creationTime": null,
                                    "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                    "lastModificationTime": null,
                                    "code": "WV",
                                    "description": "WEST VIRGINIA",
                                    "isActive": true,
                                    "locationCityState": [
                                        {
                                            "id": 108,
                                            "creatorUserId": null,
                                            "creationTime": null,
                                            "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                            "lastModificationTime": null,
                                            "cityName": "WHEELING",
                                            "isActive": true,
                                            "personnel": [],
                                            "building": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": 48,
                                                    "creatorUserId": null,
                                                    "creationTime": null,
                                                    "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                                    "lastModificationTime": null,
                                                    "isActive": true,
                                                    "buildingName": "The Valley Building",
                                                    "buildingNumber": "150",
                                                    "displayGlobal": false,
                                                    "facilityName": "The Valley Building",
                                                    "facilityNumber": "121",
                                                    "personnel": [],
                                                    "locationCityState": 108
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "id": 49,
                                                    "creatorUserId": null,
                                                    "creationTime": null,
                                                    "lastModifierUserId": null,
                                                    "lastModificationTime": null,
                                                    "isActive": true,
                                                    "buildingName": "Wheeling Field Office",
                                                    "buildingNumber": "152",
                                                    "displayGlobal": false,
                                                    "facilityName": "Wheeling Field Office",
                                                    "facilityNumber": "137",
                                                    "personnel": [],
                                                    "locationCityState": 108
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "stateCode": 58
                                        },
                                        109
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "locationCityState": 109,
                        "personnelStatus": 1,
                        "personnelType": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "creatorUserId": null,
                            "creationTime": null,
                            "lastModifierUserId": null,
                            "lastModificationTime": null,
                            "description": "Federal Employee",
                            "isActive": true,
                            "personnel": [
                                2
                            ]
                        },
                        "programOffice": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "creatorUserId": null,
                            "creationTime": null,
                            "lastModifierUserId": null,
                            "lastModificationTime": null,
                            "officeName": "OFFICE OF ENVIRONMENTAL INFORMATION",
                            "officeCode": "28000000",
                            "abbreviation": "OEI",
                            "isActive": true,
                            "personnel": [
                                2
                            ]
                        },
                        "personnelAliases": [],
                        "personnelDetail": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "creatorUserId": null,
                            "creationTime": null,
                            "lastModifierUserId": null,
                            "lastModificationTime": null,
                            "firstName": "Sunny",
                            "middleName": null,
                            "lastName": "Kosuri",
                            "suffix": null,
                            "foreignIdNumber": null,
                            "personnelAliasId": null,
                            "dateOfBirth": "2012-08-04T04:00:00.000+0000",
                            "cityOfBirth": "Hyderabad",
                            "isUSCitizen": true,
                            "address1": "11683 chanceford drive",
                            "address2": null,
                            "addressCity": "Woodbridge",
                            "postalCode": "22192",
                            "homePhoneNumber": "7033495634",
                            "cellPhoneNumber": "2017665523",
                            "homeEmailAddress": "sunilkosuri@gmail.com",
                            "height": "6.0",
                            "weight": "175",
                            "hairColor": "Black",
                            "eyeColor": "Blue",
                            "birthStateCode": null,
                            "birthCountryCode": null,
                            "citizenshipCountryCode": null,
                            "addressStateCode": null,
                            "addressCountryCode": null,
                            "personnel": 2,
                            "ssn": "175445565"
                        },
                        "personResponsible": null,
                        "pivcardInfo": [],
                        "upn": "042100005264",
                        "upnflagCode": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "creatorUserId": null,
                            "creationTime": null,
                            "lastModifierUserId": null,
                            "lastModificationTime": null,
                            "code": "SYSTEM",
                            "description": "SYSTEM generated code",
                            "isActive": true,
                            "personnel": [
                                2
                            ]
                        },
                        "vcases": []
                    },
                    3
                ]
            },
            "personnelType": null,
            "programOffice": {
                "id": 8,
                "creatorUserId": null,
                "creationTime": null,
                "lastModifierUserId": null,
                "lastModificationTime": null,
                "officeName": "OFFICE OF ADMINISTRATION AND RESOURCES MANAGEMENT",
                "officeCode": "30000000",
                "abbreviation": "OARM",
                "isActive": true,
                "personnel": [
                    3
                ]
            },
            "personnelAliases": [],
            "personnelDetail": {
                "id": 7,
                "creatorUserId": "sunil",
                "creationTime": "2018-06-03T03:09:02.802+0000",
                "lastModifierUserId": "sunil",
                "lastModificationTime": "2018-06-03T03:09:02.802+0000",
                "firstName": "Sunil",
                "middleName": null,
                "lastName": "Kosuri",
                "suffix": null,
                "foreignIdNumber": null,
                "personnelAliasId": null,
                "dateOfBirth": "1972-02-02T04:09:02.695+0000",
                "cityOfBirth": "Arlington",
                "isUSCitizen": true,
                "address1": "11632 Chanceford Drive",
                "address2": null,
                "addressCity": "Fairfax",
                "postalCode": "22192",
                "homePhoneNumber": "7033495634",
                "cellPhoneNumber": null,
                "homeEmailAddress": "sunilkosuri@gmail.com",
                "height": "6.0",
                "weight": "175",
                "hairColor": "Black",
                "eyeColor": "Brown",
                "birthStateCode": null,
                "birthCountryCode": null,
                "citizenshipCountryCode": null,
                "addressStateCode": null,
                "addressCountryCode": null,
                "personnel": 3,
                "ssn": "123432222"
            },
            "personResponsible": null,
            "pivcardInfo": [],
            "upn": null,
            "upnflagCode": null,
            "vcases": []
        },
        2
    ]
}
```

I also have configured the following:

```
package com.stsi.pss;

import com.stsi.pss.application.Email.Dto.SendEmailInput;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Authorization.permissions.PermissionsEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Authorization.roles.RolesEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Authorization.users.UsersEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Email.MailMessagesEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Model.*;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Model.LookupEntities.*;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Organizations.OrganizationUnitsEntity;
import com.stsi.pss.domain.Settings.SettingsEntity;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(PersonnelEntity.class);

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  What should I change in order to return the full object graphs for both the entities in the search result INSTEAD of the object graph only for the first entity and ids for the rest?

Comment: I don't think "2" is id of second entity

Comment: I did check the database and the it looks like the second entity's id = 2.  It's also possible that this is just a coincidence.

Comment: Could you share your dto properties

Comment: I already shared it above: The DTO is GetPageablePersonnelOutput and it has just one property: private List<PersonnelEntity> personnel;

Comment: Also, I looked at the return type "rs" in the RestContoller in a debugger and it does have the two personnel entity graphs.  Therefore, during the conversion from "rs" to JSON output, the second entity's graph is not showing and instead the number 2 (id?) is showing.

Comment: This has been fixed.  I had to change all the relationships in my system from bi-directional to uni-directional and this solved the problem.